# Uploaded pypi package missing module on install

Tags: python-3.x, pypi

I have created a python package and would like to distribute it on pypi ( https://pypi.org/project/catapi.py/ ). My initial v0.1.1 upload worked without issue. I decided to add in a sub directory to store abstract classes because there was a lot of code reuse. Upon uploading this to pypi and installing, I get the message that the abc module does not exist.

I did some research and found that I must include the subdirectory in the MANIFEST.in file, so I did. Upon uploading and attempting an install again, I get the same error. I downloaded the package directly and extracted the files to find the abc directory does indeed exist. Next I checked the site-packages version of catapi only to find it does not have the abc module.

Has anyone encountered this and know how to fix this? Here's a script to show the issue

```
# make a temp dir to hold this in
mkdir catapi
cd catapi

# Prepare python venv
python -m venv env-catapi
source env-catapi/bin/activate
pip install catapi.py==0.3.4

# Download file for comparison
wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/ee/044c1cc53e7c994fe4a7d57362651da8adff54eb34680c66f62a1d4fb57d/catapi.py-0.3.4.tar.gz
tar -xvf catapi.py-0.3.4.tar.gz
diff catapi.py-0.3.4/catapi env-catapi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/catapi
deactivate
cd ../

# Prints out
# Only in catapi: abc
# Only in env-catapi/lib/python3.8/site-packages/catapi: __pycache__
```

Answer (score 0):

It's necessary to add in the sub-directories into the

```
packages=['package1', 'package2', 'etc']
```

part of setup.py. In my case, I had to add in the abc directory to have it placed in the catapi install

```
packages=['catapi', 'catapi.abc'],
```